# Why is it that Java NIO Download works on Windows but returns Forbidden 403 on macOS?

Tags: java, macos, http

I have a small command-line program that I wrote for re-downloading files from a server in bulk. It works flawlessly in Windows, but doesn't seem to work in macOS.

Here is the error I receive:

```
Download failed: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL:
https://cdn.modrinth.com/data/P7dR8mSH/versions/0.56.3+1.19/fabric-api-0.56.3%2B1.19.jar
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1914)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1512)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1092)
    at main.downloadUsingNIO(main.java:37)
    at main.main(main.java:20)
```

Relevant code:

```
   private static void downloadUsingNIO(String urlStr, String file) throws IOException {
       URL url = new URL(urlStr);
       ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(url.openStream());
       FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
       fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
       fos.close();
       rbc.close();
   }
```

Usage:

```
downloadUsingNIO(URLOFFILE, WHERETOSAVEANDTOWHATFILE);
```

Other information:

1. Both windows and macos accounts used are the primary administrator accounts.
2. running the jar with elevated permissions through "sudo java -jar " does not fix it.
3. The file is downloadable in safari with the same link.
4. The download works with "curl -o thing.jar "
5. Tried Apache Commons.IO, didn't do anything as it uses the same code underneath (the stacktrace was the same)

---

Thank you for the answers, this is the code that I used to fix the issue:

```
private static void downloadUsingNIO(String Strurl, String path) throws IOException {

        final URLConnection connection = new URL(Strurl).openConnection();
        connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0");

        final int contentLength = connection.getContentLength();
        final File end = new File(path);

        if (end.exists()) {
            final URLConnection savedFileConnection = end.toURI().toURL().openConnection();
            if (savedFileConnection.getContentLength() == contentLength) {
                return;
            }
        } else {
            final File dir = end.getParentFile();
            if (!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdirs();
        }

        final ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(connection.getInputStream());
        final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(end);
        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
        fos.close();
        
        return;
    }
```

Comment: My guess is that you don't have the right permissions set on the Mac. Don't much about MacOS, but I have a feeling that you need to set read/write privileges correctly for either the logged user or the application.

Comment: What do you mean by that? AFAIK, sudo is the only way to elevate a program, and the issue persists regardless of the elevation. Granted, I'm basing off linux knowledge, macOS might work entirely differently. @hfontanez

Comment: I would check your firewall, and all the firewalls in between this system and the outside world.  Maybe try `traceroute` to see where the packets die.

Comment: Think about this... in Windows, if you are not an admin user, you will be denied access to a user folder that isn't the current user. I am sure MacOS has something similar. That's my guess.

Comment: If your client gets a 403 response, then shouldn't the server's error_log reveal the cause?

Comment: Well it has nothing to do with (1), NIO, (2) Java, (3) `sudo`, (4) local file permissions. The *server* denied you access. It doesn't know about any of these things. Possibly you got bounced by a local HTTP proxy.

Comment: @user207421 how would you suggest modifying the code above so it gives me more information (e.g the response body)? It seems downloading it every other way besides NIO works.

Comment: Is Java downloading from the Mac system in question?  Then I'm going to guess that the SSL layer may not be working right for NIO.  I haven't looked at SSL on top of NIO thoroughly myself, so I'm sorta guessing.

Comment: @markspace Java is downloading to the mac. Unless I read your question wrong.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the code. Do you have a local proxy set? and does Java know about it?

Comment: @markspace The fact that a 403 response was received proves that it doesn't have anything to do with SSL.

Comment: I removed all the code that attempts to clean up errors and added the full? error stack trace.

Comment: @NoThrottle That's a fair point, I was thinking about it in terms of a Java IO error, not in terms of the server actually replying with an error code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With high probably, the HTTP server doesn't like the Java default [user agent](http://www.useragentstring.com)  header, which is being sent - or it's absence; use another client. This can easily be validated by comparing the server logs. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.3

The point is, that neither NIO `Channel` nor `URL` permit setting that header.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I have now moved to using a URLconnection to download the file. Thank you!